# CSS: Superseding h1 linebreak

Tags: html, css

What would be the proper way to do this? I have an `<h1>` tag, and I want to display a `<a>` that is inline with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
display: inline
```

should do the trick. It will make the `<h1>` behave like any inline element.

Answer (score 1):

By default the h1 tag has a display:block; Thus changing it to display:inline you will lose the normal feel of an h1. But your link will directly follow it.

Also why not just place the link within the h1 tag? ie:

```
<h1>Hello <a href="http://www.example.com"> World</a></h1>
```

Comment: The h1 tag is a structural tag. It tells the browser something about the structure of the document. The anchor might not be part of this structural element: it can be a link to the edit page of a blog article or wiki part. You might just want to show it inline with the header, although it is part of the underlying content.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could float it to the left (or right):

```
float: left;
```

However, this can cause other problems sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, `margin-top: - height-of-h1` on `a` could do the trick - you have like 1000 options (almost literally), we can't tell you more until we see some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a  tag:

```
<h1>Important title <span style="float:right"><a href="#">Link</a></span></h1>
```